# Will intel Wifi AX200 work with ubuntu 20.4 in WIFI 6 mode

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

Intel Wifi AX200 wifi 6 compatibility with Ubuntu 20.04. Or 20.10
If so can anyone sugest a descktop adapter- preferably intel manufactured board.
I have a tp-link AX1500 Wifi router used with Windows 10.
Can you include detailed instruction in Kernel, Firmware, and Driver modifications if needbe.
I'm pretty new to these thing.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you have an Intel AX200 now? Are you looking for guidance to get it working in Wifi 6 mode? Are you currently running Ubuntu 20.04 or else 20.10? What have you tried so far? Or are you looking for a completely new card? ??

Comment: Looking to buy one if Wifi 6 can be implimented. I have 20.04, I can easily upgrade to 20.10. I seem to read AX200 chipset supports wifi 6, but have read yes and no.

Comment: There are a few posts about this subject; viz: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=802.11ax Can it work? Yes. Is it likely to be trouble free? Probably not. Until you install the card and try it, we don't yet know what, if any, problems might arise. There are many of us here that will be very happy to assist you.

Comment: I bought this one just know, claims Ubuntu compadability and some reviewers confirm this, (Ubit AX WiFi 6 WiFi Card Dual Band 3000 Mbps AX200 PCIE Wireless WLAN WiFi Card with Bluetooth 5.1). Will report results soon.

Comment: Both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth card work on Arch

`lspci` describes the Wi-Fi card as: Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29). `dmesg` will make a note of the device with:
iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x324

`lsusb`describes the Bluetooth device as: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. `dmesg` will make a note of the device with:
usb 2-14: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-14: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0025, bcdDevice= 0.02
usb 2-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0